# Reduce code into one string

Tags: javascript

```
blocks['package'].fadeIn();
blocks['optional'].fadeIn();
blocks['setup1'].fadeIn();
blocks['payment'].fadeIn();
```

How can I oprimize this code into general behavior, tried something like :

```
blocks['package', 'optional', 'setup1', 'payment'].fadeIn();
```

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: I'm assuming `blocks['package']`, etc. are jQuery objects.  If so, you can try: `blocks['package'].add(blocks['optional'], blocks['setup1'], blocks['payment']).fadeIn();` (or something like that).

Comment: there are many duplicated thing like it on the project

Comment: okey, so as i understand - there is no easy way to do it)

Comment: Super easy in jQuery - `$("#package, #optional, #setup1, #payment").fadeIn();`  Every jQuery object is a collection.  Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Libraries like Underscore.js or lodash make this kind of thing easy, but you can also do it easily with a simple loop:

```
var fades = ['package', 'optional', 'setup1', 'payment'];
for (var i = 0; i < fades.length; i++) {
  blocks[fades[i]].fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: that looks like 4 lines of code to replace...4 lines of code. Don't bother.

Comment: @zzzzBov don't bother optimizing because you assume it will always be 4?  What if it turned into 400?

Comment: If you are certain that those are the only four you will ever have, yes. But why not make the code more robust and extensible?

Comment: @chazsolo, when it's time to turn it into 400, then optimize for 400. Don't make your code more complicated any sooner than it needs to be.

Comment: @zzzzBov This doesn't add any unnecessary complexity and is a clean way to handle the sort of iterative functionality he is asking about.